# undefined method `get_access_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, twitter-gem

My twitter controller code is this

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
     unless TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
      redirect_to "/twitter_profile"
    end
  end

  def generate_twitter_oauth_url
    oauth_callback = "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/oauth_account"

    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("n3yfOi9iEHwnyz5uEsyNotW6t","kqHFm5dRRX00dIQSwBcTEJKZNAzrWcuK0BOAyDVWY8liRI1cPc", :site => "https://api.twitter.com")

    @request_token = @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => oauth_callback)
    session[:request_token] = @request_token

    redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => oauth_callback)
  end


  def oauth_account
    if TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
      @request_token = session[:request_token]
      @access_token = @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params["oauth_verifier"])
      TwitterOauthSetting.create(atoken: @access_token.token, asecret: @access_token.secret, user_id: current_user.id)
      update_user_account()
    end
    redirect_to "/twitter_profile"
  end

  def twitter_profile
    @user_timeline = get_client.user_timeline
    @home_timeline = get_client.home_timeline
  end

private

  def get_client    
    Twitter.configure do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "n3yfOi9iEHwnyz5uEsyNotW6t"
      config.consumer_secret     = "kqHFm5dRRX00dIQSwBcTEJKZNAzrWcuK0BOAyDVWY8liRI1cPc"
    end

    Twitter::Client.new(
      :oauth_token => TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).atoken,
      :oauth_token_secret => TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).asecret
    )
  end

  def update_user_account
    user_twitter_profile = get_client.user
    current_user.update_attributes({
      name: user_twitter_profile.name, 
      screen_name: user_twitter_profile.screen_name, 
      url: user_twitter_profile.url, 
      profile_image_url: user_twitter_profile.profile_image_url, 
      location: user_twitter_profile.location, 
      description: user_twitter_profile.description
    })
  end

end
```

On index page add your twitter account option is there. After clicking on that it will authorize app & After authorizaion process i am facing an error "undefined method `get_access_token' .i am facing error in this line " @access_token = @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params["oauth_verifier"])"

Comment: The error is telling you that `@request_token` is nil, since that is the thing that's having `get_access_token` called on it.  That in turn suggests that `session[:request_token]` is nil: you need to cater for this situation, ie that nobody has been authed yet.

Comment: MaxWilliams thanxx for your comment .But @consumer is not nil.Because i put logger on it

Comment: I didn't say anything about `@consumer`

Comment: can u suggest solution for this problem...

Comment: @MaxWilliams request_token is not empty.I put logger on request_token

Comment: how can i tweet from rails app........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of my problem:
What i did  is I added  a new method to prepare access token & in get client method  used `Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|` and also provided access_token & access_token_secret_key and now it is working properly.

```
class TwitterController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    unless TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
      redirect_to "/twitter_profile"
    end
  end

  def generate_twitter_oauth_url

    oauth_callback = "http://#{request.host}:#{request.port}/oauth_account"
    @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("2K763Dgw9y6oAOOLsegegkHW7","pwXauJeR628SL8DhgwikStNYykGCKoabISHI4ZUnKIxt2eSmNY", :site => "https://api.twitter.com")
    @request_token = @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => oauth_callback)

    session[:request_token] = @request_token
    redirect_to @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => oauth_callback)

  end


  def oauth_account
    if TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
      @request_token = session[:request_token]
      prepare_access_token(params[:oauth_token],params[:oauth_token_secret])
      @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(params[:oauth_token],params[:oauth_token_secret], :site => "https://api.twitter.com")
      @access_token = prepare_access_token(params[:oauth_token],params[:oauth_token_secret])
      TwitterOauthSetting.create(atoken: @access_token.token, asecret: @access_token.secret, user_id: current_user.id)
      update_user_account()
    end
    redirect_to "/twitter_profile"
  end

  def twitter_profile
    @user_timeline = get_client.user_timeline
    @home_timeline = get_client.home_timeline
  end

private

  def get_client    
   Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = "n3yfOi9iEHwnyz5uEsyNotW6t"
      config.consumer_secret  = "kqHFm5dRRX00dIQSwBcTEJKZNAzrWcuK0BOAyDVWY8liRI1cPc"
      config.access_token = "access_token key"
      config.access_token_secret = "access_token_secret key"
    end
  end

  def update_user_account
    user_twitter_profile = get_client.user
    current_user.update_attributes({
      name: user_twitter_profile.name, 
      screen_name: user_twitter_profile.screen_name, 
      url: user_twitter_profile.url, 
      profile_image_url: user_twitter_profile.profile_image_url, 
      location: user_twitter_profile.location, 
      description: user_twitter_profile.description
    })
  end

  def prepare_access_token(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
      #consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("APIKey", "APISecret", { :site => "https://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header })
      @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new("2K763Dgw9y6oAOOLsegegkHW7","pwXauJeR628SL8DhgwikStNYykGCKoabISHI4ZUnKIxt2eSmNY", { :site => "https://api.twitter.com", :scheme => :header })

      # now create the access token object from passed values
      token_hash = { :oauth_token => oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret => oauth_token_secret }
      access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(@consumer, token_hash )

      return access_token
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `@request_token` is apparently a string, which is why the `get_access_token` method is undefined.

Replace the `oauth_account` method with the one below to recreate the `@request_token` because `@request_token = session[:request_token]` will create a string instead and the `get_access_token` method is hence undefined.

```
def oauth_account
    if TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?

      # Re-create the request token
      @consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(ENV["consumer_key"], ENV["consumer_secret"], :site => "https://api.twitter.com")
      @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@consumer, session[:request_token], session[:request_secret])

      @access_token = @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params["oauth_verifier"])
      TwitterOauthSetting.create(atoken: @access_token.token, asecret: @access_token.secret, user_id: current_user.id)
      update_user_account()
    end
        redirect_to "/twitter_profile"
    end
```

Replace the `get_client` method with the one below to access the user's token and its access which are stored in the session.

```
def get_client
    Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key = ENV["consumer_key"]
          config.consumer_secret = ENV["consumer_secret"]

      unless TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).nil?
        config.oauth_token = TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).atoken
        config.oauth_token_secret = TwitterOauthSetting.find_by_user_id(current_user.id).asecret
      end

    end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Check using logger the value of `@acces_token`. Maybe it is not getting the required value or datatype.

Comment: Yeah i checked that request_token is  getting  value Then i put logger on access_token  & i saw that it's not receiving any value